# How do I change the order before MySQL grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

If there is more than 1 identical number in the table, I only bring one. But before bringing it, the first added date comes from the records. I want the last added record to come.

Here is an example;

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE phone_number='01234'
```

Output:

```
id | phone | created_at
-----------------------
1   01234   2020-10-27
2   01234   2020-10-28
```

MySQL code;

```
SELECT * FROM comments GROUP BY phone_number ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

MySQL output;

```
id | phone | created_at
-----------------------
1   01234   2020-10-27
```

Comment: Does `id` field correlate with `created_at`? In other words is record with greater id have greater created date?

Comment: Your group by usage is invalid (standard) SQL to begin with and any self-respecting SQL database would refuse to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the most recent *row*, you don't want aggregation.  Instead, filter for it:

```
select c.*
from c
where c.created_at = (select max(c2.created_at)
                      from comments c2
                      where c2.phone = c.phone
                     );
```

Or use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by phone order by created_at desc) as seqnum
      from comments c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, if you want this just for one phone, then you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.*
from c
where phone = '3244003390'
order by c.created_at desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: The first query returns multiple records with same `created_at` value

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev . . . It is unusual for two records to be created at exactly the same time -- but perhaps you are not storing the time as well as the date.

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use window functions for this purpose:

```
select * from (
  select 
      comments.*,
      row_number() over (partition by phone order by created_at desc) row_num
  from comments
) c where row_num = 1;
```

Test it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=b5147f425f7a7a6ed8792a92734ce4ce&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Just in case then `created_at` column correlate with `id` you can use next approach:

```
select 
    max(id) id,
    phone,
    max(created_at) created_at
from comments
group by phone;
```

It returns last `id` and last `created_at` values for each `phone` and works with old MySQL versions.

[SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d51b81e7185388c752dcad093c9e9dac&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

Something along this lines, using id since its faster and there is no real reason to use created_at:

```
SELECT t.*  FROM  comments t 
        WHERE t.id = (SELECT MAX(t2.id) FROM comments t2
        WHERE t2.phone = t.phone)
```

Comment: Just in case when rows inserted in chronological order.

Comment: Yes, but thats the case for 99% of systems , if this was a big system with master-slaves and multiple instances he would not be asking here. :)